# The setup routines for the Oracle in instantclient_12_1 ODBC driver could not be loaded due to system error code 998

Tags: sql, oracle, odbc

I am trying to connect with oracle database by using oracle instant client 32 bit because i have 32 bit pc installed i have installed oracle instant client 32 bit successfully and configure Environment variable but when i try to configure instant client in ODBC ADMINISTRATOR i am getting this error
"The setup routines for the Oracle in instantclient_12_1 ODBC driver could not be loaded due to system error code 998".i have installed microsoft redistribute c++ for 32 bit also still it is not working please advise me.

Comment: This is a setup issue, not a programming problem. As such, I suggest this question would be better asked on one of the other StackExchange sites, such as SuperUser.

Comment: A 32-bit Windows in 2016,  are you sure?

Comment: The Oracle Instant client does not include ODBC driver. You have to download and install separately.

Comment: Wernfried Domscheit can you give me the link to download ODBC driver i am using 32  bit pc and let me inform you that i used this two setup 1)instantclient-basic-nt-12.1.0.2.0
          2)instantclient-odbc-nt-12.1.0.2.0  and configure in 32 bit windows but in other 32 bit pc it was working.

Comment: You can download from here: [Oracle Data Access Components (ODAC) for Windows Downloads](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/utilsoft-087491.html)

Comment: can you give me a snap of exact one because there are many version in the screen and i am confusing here which one should i select.

Answer (score -1):

I just copied the working dlls `sqlora32.dll` , `sqoras32.dll`, `sqlresus.dll` and it worked for me but before that make sure you have correct entry in Registry, Environment variables are very well set also.

On Windows 64-bit OS,
32-bit AND 64-bit USER ODBC data sources are stored in the registry under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\ODBC\ODBC.INI`
64-bit SYSTEM ODBC data sources are stored in the registry under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBC.INI`
32-bit SYSTEM ODBC data sources are stored in the registry under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\ODBC\ODBC.INI`